# How to delete inside a tableView?

Tags: swift

I have this swift code for an ios app.

I was working on the tableView, in order to make the swipe to the left,in order to delete a list of locations saved by the user.

The part with the questions marks is the critical park and I can't figure out what I have to put or where is the mistake...

Thank you in advance

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class PlacesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self,
      selector: #selector(newLocationAdded(_:)),
      name: .newLocationSaved,
      object: nil)
  }

  @objc func newLocationAdded(_ notification: Notification) {
    tableView.reloadData()
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return LocationsStorage.shared.locations.count
  }




    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete{

            ???.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        }

    }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlaceCell", for: indexPath)
    let location = LocationsStorage.shared.locations[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
    cell.textLabel?.text = location.description
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = location.dateString
    return cell
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 110
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that `LocationsStorage.shared.locations` is an array, you're fine to use `LocationsStorage.shared.locations.remove(at: indexPath.row)`. If you're facing issues with this, please specify the error you get so that I can help further

```
LocationsStorage.shared.locations.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

On a side note, also make sure you add `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` when you're modifying the tableView by performing multiple inserts/deletes.

Edit:-

Since you get "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'locations' setter is inaccessible", which clearly means that you have read-only access to the array, you have two options..

1) Go to the singleton class(LocationsStorage class) and change the `locations` collection to make it mutable. (You may/may not want to do this. But if you have the need to modify the array of the singleton through the tableView, you have no other choice)

2) If you don't really feel the need to modify the array of the singleton class, you can have your own local collection at the class where you handle the tableView like `var myLocationArray = LocationsStorage.shared.locations` and use this array as your datasource

Comment: `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` has no effect in this case. It's only required for multiple simultaneous insert/delete/move operations.

Comment: If I put LocationsStorage.shared.locations I get: "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'locations' setter is inaccessible"

Comment: Have edited the answer. Do let me know if you have trouble doing something

Answer (score 0):

As `LocationsStorage.shared.locations` is the datasource array just replace ??? with it

```
 if editingStyle == .delete{
    LocationsStorage.shared.locations.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
 }
```

Comment: If I put LocationsStorage i get: "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'locations' setter is inaccessible"

Comment: Then change the data model and make the `locations` property mutable. You cannot delete a row without removing the item in the data source. Or is there an API to remove objects in `LocationsStorage`?

Comment: How can I do this properly? (Sorry but this error makes me crazy :/)

Comment: I have no idea because I don't know `LocationsStorage`.

Comment: Can I share the file with PasteBin?

Comment: Remove `private(set)` in front of `var locations...`

Comment: It works like a charm... what a stupid mistake... thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: Rip. It deletes the locations saved but if I close the app and than I open it again, all the locations that I'v delete before are still there... what is wrong? :/

Comment: If you remove a location from the data source you have to delete also the corresponding file on disk.

Comment: So i have to add: "saveLocationOnDisk.remove(at: indexPath.row)"?

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Each location is saved as a file on disk. You have to identify the file and delete it with `FileManager`. But it seems that the `Location` struct or class doesn't contain the file name which makes it quite difficult and cumbersome.

Comment: Please ask a new question how to delete a location. Add the `LocationsStorage` class and also the `Location` object.

Answer (score -1):

For what I can see you have to delete from

```
LocationsStorage.shared.locations
```

The next part of the code seem fine and then you just have to do the

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

again to see the changes reflected in the table.

Comment: I'v made the var with my tableView.reloadData(). But I get "Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. "

Comment: **Never** call `tableView.reloadData()` right after `insert-/deleteRows`.  `deleteRows` does update the UI

Comment: Well it can be an option to just delete the item in the datasource and then reload the data, it will have the same output